# Dompdf text not wrapping in table cell

Tags: laravel, word-wrap, dompdf

Can someone explain this to me please, i have a Laravel app (probably not important) and am using dompdf when i use the HTML below

```
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
   
</body>
</html>
```

out of the box i get this....

[image]

Why does the text not wrap around, and why does it go off the screen, am i missing something really obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Adding **style="white-space:wrap"** worked for me. It justifies the text and matches the cell width.

```
<td style="white-space:wrap">My long text goes here. My long text goes here. My long text goes here. My long text goes here. My long text goes here. My long text goes here. My long text goes here. My long text goes here. My long text goes here.</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some style not working on dom-pdf so for now just try with giving black solid border of 1px to

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code in your CSS:

```
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```